# fill select list conditionally in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a select list that should be filled conditionally .

here is the condtion :
**function that get data**

```
function getDocumentTypeList() {

         BaseInfoService.getDocumentTypeList().then(function (data) {
             $scope.documentTypeList = data;
             $scope.requestAuthorization.DocumentType = 0
             $scope.conditionalLabel();
             debugger;
         });

     }
////////////////////////////
     function getSpecialList() {

         BaseInfoService.getSpecialList().then(function (data) {
             $scope.specialList = data;
             debugger;
         });

     }
```

there is select list that define which one should be shown .

If value ===1 ng-option fill from `people`
if value === 2  ng-option fill from `person`
  [**[Fiddle][1](http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/420/)**](http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/420/)

Thanks

Comment: And what is "value"? And where is it defined?

Comment: there is another select list that has 2 values , 0 and 1

Comment: I don't see any select lists in this code.  There may be select lists in the fiddle, but since they are the focal point of the question, they should be listed in the question itself.  The two functions you did list aren't relevant to the question, since they bring no context with them (i.e. no indication how either of them are called) and don't seem to be what is not functioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption: shape of the two lists are similar.

You can have a scope function as your source and in that function do if or switch statement to figure out what source to use.

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  
  angular.module('myApp', []);
  
  angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);
  
  myCtrl.$inject = ['$log'];
  function myCtrl($log) {
    var self = this;
    
    var ducks = [
      { name: 'Donald' },
      { name: 'Daisy' }
    ];
    
    var mice = [
      { name: 'Mickey' },
      { name: 'Minnie' }
    ];
    
    self.listType = 2;  //change to 1 for ducks, 2 or anything else for mice
    self.selectedThing = null;
    
    self.getListOptions = function() {
      switch(self.listType) {
          case '1': return ducks;
          case '2': 
          default:
            return mice;
      }
    }
  }
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
  
  <label for="radType1"><input type="radio" name="radType" id="radType1" ng-model="vm.listType" value="1">Ducks</label>
  <label for="radType2"><input type="radio" name="radType" id="radType2" ng-model="vm.listType" value="2">Mice</label>
  
  <br>
  <select ng-options="o.name for o in vm.getListOptions()" ng-model="vm.selectedThing">
  </select>
</div>
```